# How to change Codename One's time picker's font color?

Tags: codenameone

I get this result (on simulator and Android):

[image]

I tried to change different style selectors but can't find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The [Picker Component](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) is implemented natively and as a result can't be customized properly. The way it looks on the simulator doesn't represent it's appearance on the device.

You are using Date & Time Picker which I wouldn't recommend, it's an iOS specific picker type that isn't supported on other OS's. I would recommend using separate pickers for other OS's.

E.g. this is how the date picker looks on my Android device:

[image: Date picker in Codename One on Android]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You wrote about using "separate pickers" for OSs, where can I find them? Or do I have to write my own date/time picker?

Comment: It's implemented by Picker. It means **our** implementation of `Picker` differs for every OS